# Find the expected value of the largest number in the sample.

Tags: probability, random-variables, means

*An urn contains N cards numbered from 1 to N. A random experiment
It consists of selecting n cards at random and with replacement. Find the expected value of the largest number in the sample.*

The answer is $N - \frac{1}{N^{n}} \Sigma_{k=1}^{N-1}k^{n}$ but I don´t how justify it.

Comment: What is the probability that the largest number is $k?$

Comment: Reality check: Simulating a million draws of $n=5$ from among cards $\{1, 2, \dots, N=13\}$ in R using the code `b = replicate(10^6, max(sample(1:13, 5, repl=T))); mean(b)` gives 11.298 to about 2 places; 'answer' computes to about 11.301.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let M be the largest number drawn.  Then $\Pr(M=1)=N^{-n}.$  Suppose $k>1.$  Then for $M$ to be equal to $k$ it must be the case that every number drawn is $\le k$ and it must not be the case that every number drawn is $\le k-1$.  That is, $$Pr(M=k)=\begin{cases}
N^{-n},&k=1\\
N^{-n}(k^n-(k-1)^n),&2\le k\le N 
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, $$
E(M)= N^{-n}(1+\sum_{k=2}^N{[k^{n+1}-k(k-1)^n]},$$
and the only problem is evaluating the sum.  In evaluating the sum, there is substantial telescoping.  If you don't see it offhand, I suggest working it out for say $N=4$.  You will spot the pattern, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ enumerate the highest card selected in the sample; so $$\mathsf P(X>k)=\left(1-\left(1-\frac{k}{N}\right)^n\right)\mathbf 1_{k\in\{1..N\}}$$

Then the expected value is $$\begin{split}\mathsf E(X) &= \sum_{j=1}^{N} j~\mathsf P(X=j)\\ &= \sum_{j=1}^{N} \sum_{k=0}^{j-1} \mathsf P(X=j) \\ & = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \sum_{j=k+1}^{N}\mathsf P(X=j)\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\mathsf P(X>k) \end{split}$$

and so...

Comment: We know that P(X > k) = 1 - P(k), but I've been trying to get P (k), but I do not know how to do it, could you help me one more time?

Comment: $P(X>k)$ is the probability for selecting some of the $N-k$ numbers greater than $k$ at least once among the $n$ trials. So that is $\big(1-(1-\frac{N-k}{N})^n\big)$